# volley post request getting wrong response but postman getting correct response

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volley library in my project to connect database, but i am facing an issue.
When i use volley library in my code to post data to web getting wrong response always , but when i test in postman getting correct response.. 
i can't solve this issue. anyone can help me...

i am post my code and postman response here

Volley request

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("response", response);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("error_code"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "json exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("username", name);
            data.put("email", email);
            data.put("password", password);
            return data;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SignUpActivity.this);
    queue.getCache().clear();
    //queue.getCache().remove(REGISTER_URL);
    //request.setShouldCache(false);
    queue.add(request);
```

Response when use volley

```
{"error_code":"1","error_message":"Email already exist !"}
```

Response from postman

```
{"error_code":"0","error_message":" "}
```

Comment: you are trying first from postman and then volley? Or first from volley and then postman?

Comment: retrofit 2 is way more better then the mess u have done in this code

Comment: Could you share the API?

Comment: Are you using any query param in GET request?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed used both

Comment: for sure you have missed something while requesting, for me i see that the volley request is the right one, so please make sure that you did not miss any configs, any headers or authentications while sending.

Comment: @AbuQauod what config i have missed.

Comment: @SharafudheenKannath for example [Content-Type, Authorization, User-Agent, Accept-Language, etc...]